# Align Total Text Box under specific DataGridView columns - Win Forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview where I have 12 columns (example: Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, and Col12) and in the different panel, have text boxes to display total of some columns (textbox1col4, textbox2col5, textbox3col6, textbox4col7, textbox5col8, textbox6col9, and textbox7col10). The problem here is whenever I load data on datagridview, these total text boxes are not aligned, looked too far away from the specific column. I want whenever I load data in datagridview then textbox1col4 come under Col4, textbox2col5 come under Col5, textbox3col6 come under Col6, and so on. I am not sure how to start the code and what code and where I need to add the code. If anyone can help to provide a sample code or a suggestion to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [DataGridView.GetColumnDisplayRectangle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getcolumndisplayrectangle) + [Control.RectangleToScreen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.rectangletoscreen) + [Control.RectangleToClient()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.rectangletoclient). Then offset the resulting rectangle with the corresponding TextBox bounds, e.g.,  `textbox1col4.SetBounds(rect.X, textbox1col4.Top, rect.Width, textbox1col4.Height);`

Comment: Each time you reset your DGV's DataSource and when the DGV is resized.

Comment: Thanks, Jimi. It worked for me. Hurray :)                                                         Rectangle RecValue = dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(1, true);
txt1Col1.SetBounds(RecValue .X, txt1Col1.Top, RecValue.Width, txt1Col1.Height);